# Infopath form is displyed as xml in a form library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I am creating new forms in InfoPath and when the form is filled out and submitted the form is turned into an xml file. I have gone through all of the wizards of publishing InfoPath forms and did not see any options of changing this. IS there a way for me to update the forms so they do not save as .xml?

thanks.

Comment: No, that's how it works. If you want it in another format, you'll have to print it to pdf or xps in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's how it works. InfoPath generates an XML file and transforms it via XSLT to get the form view in the browser.

If you want it in another format, you'll have to print it to pdf or xps in the browser.

Comment: Would you happen to have a reference I could read about printing the (form/xml?) to pdf or xps?

Comment: Assuming it is a browser based infopath form, it is just using the print options native to your browser and changing the output type

Comment: Eric, I was curious if there is a way for me to style that .xml file with some xslt or something when a user opens the form. Thanks.

Comment: That's what infopath does, generates xslt to style the xml file